# Context: defining fontfamily swallows characters

Tags: context

When I'm setting fontfamilies for the different styles, context seems to swallow characters that I'm printing with `\type{-}`.

I'm using `\type` to avoid getting the dash symbols merged to em-dash.

MWE:

```
\definefontfamily[mainface][serif][TeX Gyre Pagella]
\definefontfamily[mainface][sans][TeX Gyre Heros]
\definefontfamily[mainface][mono][Latin Modern Mono]
\setupbodyfont[mainface]

\starttext

{\tt test \type{-}\type{-}\type{-}} 

test \type{-}\type{-}\type{-}

\stoptext
```

The output is: `test -`

instead of the expected: `test ---`

Comment: You have to disable the `default` features for the monospace font with  `\definefontfamily[mainface][mono][Latin Modern Mono][features=none]`.

Comment: This works, but what is it doing exactly?  Should I set it for all fontfamilies?

Comment: Among others it prevents ligatures. Basically, it disables all font features enabled by default. So for a text font you usually want these features and should not disable it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Wolfgang already commented, you have to add `features=none`.  The reason is that if you omit the `features` declaration, the `default` set will be used which includes `tlig` which is the common TeX ligatures, i.e. `---` will be transformed into emdash.

The dashes are in different `\type` calls, but the ligaturing is applied at a later stage, so LuaTeX just sees three consecutive dashes and replaces them.

You could actually add empty whatsits between the dashes to suppress the ligature, i.e. `\type{-}\special{}\type{-}\special{}\type{-}` but I don't recommend that.

You also *have to* define a math family, otherwise you can't use math.  You might not think that this is a big deal, but ConTeXt may use math internally for, e.g. the itemize bullet or so.

```
\definefontfamily[mainface] [serif] [TeX Gyre Pagella]
\definefontfamily[mainface] [sans]  [TeX Gyre Heros]
\definefontfamily[mainface] [mono]  [Latin Modern Mono] [features=none]
\definefontfamily[mainface] [math]  [Latin Modern Math]
\setupbodyfont[mainface]

\starttext

{\tt test \type{-}\type{-}\type{-}} 

test \type{-}\type{-}\type{-}

$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

\stoptext
```

[image]